# Pasting a value into a new cell each time another is updated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm hoping to have 2 cells that update their value every week. Each time these cells get their values updated I would like them to also be printed onto another two cells on a different sheet. Each week these cells that they are printed onto moving down by one. For example Week 1, the two cells are printed in A1 and B1. Week 2 they are printed in A2 and B2, and so on.

I know how to do this in Excel but no idea how I can change that over to Google Sheets / Scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. Your new inputs are in `input!A1` and `input!B1`; and
2. Your outputs will by in `output!A` and `output!B`.

You can write a script by clicking on Tools on the menu and entering Script Editor.

Then write this function:

```js
function writeData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName("input")
    .getRange(1, 1, 1, 2)
    .getValues();
  var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("output");
  var numRows = outputSheet.getLastRow();

  outputSheet.getRange(numRows + 1, 1)
    .setValue(input[0][0]);
  outputSheet.getRange(numRows + 1, 2)
    .setValue(input[0][1]);
}
```

Next, set up a trigger. Within Script Editor, under Resources, select Current project's triggers and then set up your trigger. If you want it to run weekly, use a time-driven trigger. You can also set a spreadsheet-driven trigger to run on every edit. Save everything.

If you don't want to use automatic triggers, you can execute the `writeData()` function by adding an item on the menu bar of the spreadsheet:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Write data", functionName: "writeData"});
  ss.addMenu("Custom functions", menuEntries);
}
```

Save, and if you refresh the spreadsheet you'll see a new item on the menu bar.